# Streamlit for General Web Development

Tags: python-3.x, web, rapid-prototyping

I've been using Streamlit for a while. I looked everywhere I could. Does anyone else know if there is a package like Streamlit for general website development using Python?

For reference, this is [Streamlit](https://www.streamlit.io/)

Comment: Streamlit as for moment lacks a lot of production features. For general website development, the standard (AFAIK) is to use Flask with its extensions. It's more complicated for sure but you'll have more controls.

Answer (score 1):

This may not entirely answer your question, but Streamlit now has sharing functionality so you can deploy your webapp for others to easily access. See https://www.streamlit.io/sharing

That being said, Streamlit has very specific functionality that doesn't do well for generalized web development. For that you will look for [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) for a simple framework for building website and [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) if you want higher level implementation for Python web development.

Answer (score 0):

A little late and no, as of now there is not. Streamlit is designed for making Machine learning and data science web apps.
For more information, you can read this.
https://towardsdatascience.com/streamlit-101-an-in-depth-introduction-fc8aad9492f2